# How to set up an XML Feed URL

Tags: java, xml, feed

I want to post some data on a website, and they are asking me to provide them with the URL of an XML feed.

What is the URL of an XML feed? How do I create an XML feed in Java?

Answer (score 2):

XML feeds are a form of paid inclusion where a search engine is fed information about an advertiser’s web pages by XML. XML is a data delivery language that stands for “Extensible Markup Language” and allows users to define their own elements for sharing structured data. XML feeds also allow the search engine to gather information about web pages without having to gather information by crawling through pages. Marketers who are involved with an XML feed pay to have their pages included in a spider-based search index based on a XML format document which represents each advertiser’s websites

**How XML Feed works**

An RSS (Rich Site Summary or Realy Simple Syndication - depends who you ask!) feed
is an `XML feed`. RSS is a standard for the syndication of content. IT is relay powerful. There is nothing special to them at all it is just xml in a certain fromat. XML its self is not too different from HTML except that you make your own tags up and it is very strict - ie everything must be properly nested.

In RSS you start with a description of the site that produces the feed then you open a channel which contains items, titles, authors and descriptions etc. These link to the full artilces. RSS is primarily news based which is why the date bit is included.

Some Sample XML feeds are

http://twitter.com/statuses/public_timeline.xml - twitter

This tutorial explains how to create a feed in java

http://www.techiepark.com/tutorials/how-to-create-rss-or-atom-feed-using-java/

May be this will help you.

Comment: Website will hit my feed url? Will it be a simple request response cycle? I will have to simply write xml file in my response whenever that website sends any request?

Comment: Not able to understand your actual requirement and context

Comment: Just want to understand how xml feed works?
Is it just sending xml over http response?

Comment: Ok thanks. So basically it just works like a http request response cycle. For example when some website requests our feed url, well formatted xml is sent in response. Am i right?

Answer (score 1):

I guess what they're asking is that you provide an RSS feed. So, you will not post data on the web site, but the web site will fetch data from you using the RSS URL that you expose.

For writing an RSS feed with Java, you may look at this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/RSSFeed/article.html#write)

Comment: Is there anything like `non-Rss xml feed` ?

Comment: RSS is a sort of Web feed; it is XML-based. Have look at this [article in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_feed#Technical_definition)